# MySQL Database is not Indexing

Tags: solr

I am new to Solr. When I index my database, it fetches all the rows successfully, but the output is showing that they are not indexed. Here are the details:

**My data-config.xml setting**

```
    <entity name="company" query="select report_number, company_name from company">
        <field column="report_number" name="country_id"/>
        <field column="company_name" name="country_name"/> 
    </entity>
```

Report_number and company_name both are varchar datatype in the database.

**My Schema.xml file where I define the fields**

```
    <field name="country_id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" />      
    <field name="country_name" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" />
```

**This is the browser output**

[image]

Comment: Check your solr log file

Answer (score 1):

As part of the example schema a uniqueKey field is defined:

```
 <!-- Field to use to determine and enforce document uniqueness. 
      Unless this field is marked with required="false", it will be a required field
  -->
 <uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
```

As the comment states, unless you mark that field as `required="false"` you must include that field in all items being added to the index. Unless you have modified this entry to be one of your custom defined fields, you will need to change this entry in the schema.xml or supply an `id` field entry along with your other two field in your data-config.xml settings.